convert range(0,10) to a list of lists in Python3
I need to create  a list of lists from a range:
for example range(0,10) -->[[0,5],[6,10]]
I think possible to do it using list comprehension but cannot figure out a way for the same
I tried this list_com = [[x, x + 5] for x in range(0, 10, 5)]
but it gives  [[0, 5], [5, 10]]
and if I try, list_com  = [[x + 1, x + 5] for x in range(0, 10, 5)]
I get [[1, 5], [6, 10]]  which is close except for first list, where I want [[0,5],[6,10]]
Is there a better way to do it or fix the above to remove the first list bug.

Why would the output be [[0, 5], [6, 10]]? What is the relationship between the input and output?

But why [[0, 5], [6, 10]]? 0 - 5 differs 5, and 6 - 10 differs 4.

I have 201 partitions  so 1 extra partition needs to fit somewhere. we are focusing on wrong details here

You haven't provided enough details for us to even be sure what you're trying to do, let alone how to do it. All we know is that for some reason, an input of range(0, 10) should produce an output of [[0, 5], [6, 10]]. We don't know why that input would correspond to that output, or what output any other input should correspond to.

It was  a very simple problem that I figured out eventually.  There is  enough info here of what is the task . splits a range into a list comprehension. that too half solved.

The first sub-element differs from the others in that it has an inclusive range of 6 whereas all others have a range of 5.
You can eliminate the complexity of a conditional test in a list comprehension by constructing the first sub-element separately as follows:
def genElements(g=5, n=200):
    yield [0, g]
    for i in range(g, n, g):
        yield [i+1, i+g]

l = list(genElements())
print(l)


figured it out
l = [[x + 1, x + 5] if x > 0 else [x, x + 5] for x in range(0, 200, 5)]

